# mouseover not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which is not working
I create this div over a popup , normally there will be 20 divs like this on a popup.
i am trying mouseover its not working , if i give mousover event in the div itself its working. 
any mistake.

```
<div dataindex="0" class="clstImages" id="dlstImages0"><img alt="Almond Branches in Bloom, San Remy, c.1890" title="Almond Branches in Bloom, San Remy, c.1890" src="http://imagecache5d.art.com/CropHandler/crop.jpg?img=21-2107-SA3ED00Z&amp;x=0&amp;y=0&amp;w=400&amp;h=400&amp;size=2&amp;maxw=100&amp;maxh=100&amp;mode=sq&amp;q=100" id="eachimg">
</div>
```

```
$('.clstImages img').hover(function () {
    alert("mouseover");
}, function () {
    alert("mouseout")
});
```

Comment: Is the content of the div(the images) created dynamic?

Comment: Its dynamic , there will be totally 20 divs per popup, the images are inside the above divs.

Comment: any ideas why it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hover function is fine but you need to wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` function.

I believe you are trying to run the script before the DOM has finished loading.  Using `$(document).ready()`  waits until the DOM is finished loading before executing its contents.  Here is a reference to that function  [jQuery .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Also you should remember to close your image tags

`<img src="someimage" >` is NOT valid HTML

`<img src="someimage" />` is VALID HTML

Also you should remember to end your javascript statments. The following line was not terminated.

```
alert("mouseout")
```

it should be

```
alert("mouseout");
```

Note the semi-colon at the end

Here is a working [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/R7KmW/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/R7KmW/

---

**Edited**

It seems your elements are not actually populated until you click on the directional arrow.  You may want to try using  live() or delegate(). basically these two Jquery Methods allow you to bind to future DOM element (elements that inserted using code ie AJAX, Dynamically Created Element).  I know this type of answer was already posted for you but I really dont have any more time to debug your entire page for issues.  I appologize for not providing a better answer but perhaps you can create a small test of just one image with the same features and try to debug that way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clstImages img').live('mouseover', function () { 
      alert("mouseover"); 
    })
    .live('mouseout', function () { 
      alert("mouseout");
    });
});
```

Comment: Correct, though a semi-colon on the last statement isn't required. JS Minifers remove these actually :) Also, I presumed that it was all inside `$(document).ready()` because he's already, successfully creating the tooltips.

Comment: @Marco your right on the semi-colon..but for saftey sake in case your modifying your code in development and place a line after the one missing the semi-colon, then the safe bet is to always put the semi-colon. When your ready to release the code, then minify or obvuscate your javascript to shrink the size of the file. However I always try to follow recommended syntax when the file is being used for development and not minified or obvuscated.

Comment: I think there is some other problem,my mouseover function is inside ready function only. If you have time you can try the working example here , type http://www.art.com/gallery/id--b1823/animals-posters.htm?ui=76947CF94DBD4E59981ADAA5E7C14F65 mouseover any image in that gallery page and click in one of the direcionts, you will the image grid, thats where i am trying to add mousover event and its not working

Comment: Right now its not added, i am planning to add a feature on mousover and its not working , but if i give as inline...mouseover its works

Comment: The direction u provided is enough john , thanks for your time and patience.I will debug from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
`<img>` tags are self-closing so instead of `<img src="..">` you should write `<img src="..." />` Note the slash at the end.**

**Use jQuery's [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method**

> **Description:** Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

```
$('.clstImages img').live("mouseenter", function () {
    alert("mouseenter");
});
$('.clstImages img').live("mouseleave", function () {
    alert("mouseleave");
});
```

Or when you create the `<img>`, assign a click event directly *(this is probably a better approach)*.

Comment: Or combine them in a single bind: `$('selector').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) { if (event.type == 'mouseover') { // ... } else { // ... } });`