# How to pop image out of a div a little

Tags: jquery

I have images in a row , I want to popout image a alit from the div as it moving and coming out.
When we mouseover it should move a little bit.

May I know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your asking for: Using [jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourImageIdOrSelector").mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.animate({left: '+=5'}, 'fast', function() {
      $this.animate({left: '-=10'}, 'fast', function() {
        $this.animate({left: '+=5'}, 'fast', function() {
          //animation finished
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Here is an [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xbBQa/3/)  http://www.jsfiddle.net/xbBQa/3/

---

**EDITED:** Making the image appear to come closer to you or get larger. Sorry your question was hard to understand.  I did my best the first time. But here is a second stab at it.  below is the code and here is a link to a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xbBQa/5/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/xbBQa/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myimage").mouseover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
      $this.animate({height: '+=5', width: '+=5'}, 'fast', function() {
      $this.animate({height: '-=10', width: '-=10'}, 'fast', function() {
        $this.animate({height: '+=5', width: '+=5'}, 'fast', function() {
          //animation finished
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: almost close, thanks. but is it possible to popout little bit as if image is coming towards us.

Comment: @gov ... Your original question was hard to understand I have updated my answer with what I think you want.  again it is simply using jquery animate().

Comment: Hi John , can you please look at my other question, somehow image mouseover event is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001626/mouseover-not-working